# Getting previous given weekday name

Tags: php, date, datetime

One can get the first upcoming day of week by using just the name of the day with our without preceding with "this".

```
$dt=new \DateTime('7/16/2019');
echo $dt->format('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A').PHP_EOL;                               //Tuesday 16th of July 2019 12:00:00 AM

echo (clone $dt)->modify('monday')->format('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A').PHP_EOL;     //Monday 22nd of July 2019 12:00:00 AM
echo (clone $dt)->modify('tuesday')->format('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A').PHP_EOL;    //Tuesday 16th of July 2019 12:00:00 AM
echo (clone $dt)->modify('wednesday')->format('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A').PHP_EOL;  //Wednesday 17th of July 2019 12:00:00 AM
```

How can one get the previous weekday?  For instance,

- Monday 15th of July 2019 12:00:00 AM
- Tuesday 16th of July 2019 12:00:00 AM
- Wednesday 10th of July 2019 12:00:00 AM

Note that `previous` will work for all except tuesday in which it returns `Tuesday 9th of July 2019 12:00:00 AM`.

Comment: Can't you just do `previous x` and no previous for the weekday that is the same as the weekday of your `$dt`?

Comment: But the 9th is the previous Tuesday. 7/16/2019 is a Tuesday. So the previous Tuesday is the 9th.

Comment: @Kyle  I agree previous does what it should do, however, it is not what I want.

Comment: Well if your definition of previous is “off by one day”, then why don’t you simply correct it by taking that into account? _Don’t_ look at the previous days of `7/16/2019`, but add one day first …

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dt=new \DateTime('7/16/2019 00:01:00');
$dt->modify('monday');
echo $dt->format('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A').PHP_EOL;                               //Tuesday 16th of July 2019 12:00:00 AM
echo (clone $dt)->modify('previous monday')->format('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A').PHP_EOL;     //Monday 22nd of July 2019 12:00:00 AM
echo (clone $dt)->modify('previous tuesday')->format('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A').PHP_EOL;    //Tuesday 16th of July 2019 12:00:00 AM
echo (clone $dt)->modify('previous wednesday')->format('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A').PHP_EOL;
```

I set it to the next Monday, so previous always returns what you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a wrapper function that would check the weekday against the DateTime instance. If the weekday is the same as the instance, simply return a clone of the instance.

```
function getPreviousWeekday(DateTime $dt, string $weekday)
{
    if (strtolower($dt->format('l')) == strtolower($weekday)) {
        return clone $dt;
    }

    return (clone $dt)->modify($weekday);   
}
```

Then the usage would be like this:

```
echo getPreviousWeekday($dt, 'monday')->format('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A').PHP_EOL; //Monday 22nd of July 2019 12:00:00 AM
echo getPreviousWeekday($dt, 'tuesday')->format('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A').PHP_EOL; //Tuesday 16th of July 2019 12:00:00 AM
echo getPreviousWeekday($dt, 'wednesday')->format('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A').PHP_EOL; //Wednesday 17th of July 2019 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtotime` and use the `last <weekday>` to get what you want. Depending on your use case, you can try using tomorrow as the starting point.

```php
$tomorrow = strtotime('tomorrow');

$monday = date('l jS of F Y h:i:s A', strtotime('last monday', $tomorrow));
$tuesday = date('l jS of F Y h:i:s A', strtotime('last tuesday', $tomorrow));
$wednesday = date('l jS of F Y h:i:s A', strtotime('last wednesday', $tomorrow));

echo $monday.PHP_EOL;
echo $tuesday.PHP_EOL;
echo $wednesday.PHP_EOL;
```

This will return:

```
Monday 15th of July 2019 12:00:00 AM
Tuesday 16th of July 2019 12:00:00 AM
Wednesday 10th of July 2019 12:00:00 AM
```